# Apply border radius to Typeahead react js

Tags: typeahead

i  have the below code

```
                <Typeahead
                    id="ty"
                    onChange={setSelected}
                    options={options}
                    placeholder="Business type ..."
                    selected={selected}
                    style={{height:"50px",borderRadius:"200px"}}
                />
```

when I want to style the input box with border radius it is not working, how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to change the border-radius with borderRadius. because when you add style in `Typeahead` component, it will apply to only top parent element. but original border radius is applied in `input` box. you have to add custom css for this